# OSX Homebrew /usr/local permisions for node

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew, osx-elcapitan, chown

I have installed homebrew without any problems.

The problem was to install node.. I got permission errors about /usr/local directory and symlinks.

So I did

```
sudo chown -R myuser /usr/local
```

then I istalled node without problems and then I did

```
sudo chown -R root /usr/local
```

I don't remember how was the owners in first place. I just followed some suggestions from [stackoverflow](https://superuser.com/a/717683) to change the owner of /usr/local (a voice inside me says I did bad).

So when I run

```
brew doctor
```

I got some warnings and suggestions to chown some folders in /usr/local directory, so I did them. Then when I run

```
brew doctor
brew update
```

I get no warnings or errors anymore and looks fine (there was no updates to do after all).

My directories now looks like below. Can anyone confirm if is secure like that? How should be the owners in /usr/local ? Tt's okay to have it owned by my user as they say at [github](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/El_Capitan_and_Homebrew.md)? Thanks.

```
myuser@iMac:/usr$ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x@   12 root  wheel   408B Sep 30 23:52 ./
drwxr-xr-x    30 root  wheel   1.1K Jan 23 17:51 ../
drwxr-xr-x     5 root  wheel   170B Aug 23 03:51 X11/
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root  wheel     3B Sep 30 23:43 X11R6@ -> X11
drwxr-xr-x     3 root  wheel   102B Aug 27 04:17 adic/
drwxr-xr-x  1055 root  wheel    35K Jan 23 17:51 bin/
drwxr-xr-x   263 root  wheel   8.7K Jan 23 17:52 lib/
drwxr-xr-x   186 root  wheel   6.2K Jan 23 17:51 libexec/
drwxrwxr-x    22 root  admin   748B Feb  7 12:28 local/
drwxr-xr-x   243 root  wheel   8.1K Jan 23 17:51 sbin/
drwxr-xr-x    45 root  wheel   1.5K Sep 30 23:43 share/
drwxr-xr-x     4 root  wheel   136B Sep 17 09:03 standalone/
myuser@iMac:/usr$ cd local/
myuser@iMac:/usr/local$ ls -la
total 104
drwxrwxr-x  22 root                admin   748B Feb  7 12:28 ./
drwxr-xr-x@ 12 root                wheel   408B Sep 30 23:52 ../
drwxr-xr-x  15 myuser              admin   510B Feb  7 12:56 .git/
-rw-r--r--   1 root                admin   847B Feb  6 10:48 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--   1 root                admin   1.3K Feb  6 10:48 .travis.yml
-rw-r--r--   1 root                admin   291B Feb  6 10:48 .yardopts
-rw-r--r--   1 root                admin   3.1K Feb  6 10:48 CODEOFCONDUCT.md
-rw-r--r--   1 root                admin   2.5K Feb  6 10:48 CONTRIBUTING.md
drwxr-xr-x   3 myuser              admin   102B Feb  7 12:28 Cellar/
-rw-r--r--   1 root                admin   1.2K Feb  6 10:48 LICENSE.txt
drwxr-xr-x  10 myuser              admin   340B Feb  7 12:28 Library/
-rw-r--r--   1 root                admin   2.4K Feb  6 10:48 README.md
-rw-r--r--   1 root                admin    23K Feb  6 10:48 SUPPORTERS.md
drwxrwxr-x   9 root                admin   306B Feb  7 12:28 bin/
drwxr-xr-x   3 myuser              admin   102B Feb  7 12:28 etc/
drwxr-xr-x  10 root                wheel   340B Aug  3  2015 git/
drwxr-xr-x  20 root                wheel   680B Dec  3 02:01 go/
drwxr-xr-x   3 myuser              admin   102B Feb  7 12:28 include/
drwxr-xr-x   4 myuser              admin   136B Feb  7 12:28 lib/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root                wheel   102B May 15  2015 n/
drwxr-xr-x   3 myuser              admin   102B Feb  7 12:28 opt/
drwxrwxr-x   5 root                admin   170B Feb  7 12:28 share/
myuser@iMac:/usr/local$
```

Comment: The group on all my homebrew stuff below `/usr/local/bin` is set to `admin` and I haven't changed it from the default.

Comment: Which user you have at `/usr/local/bin`? root or your regular use? I think should be your regular user, if you installed without sudo, right? Can you make an `ls -la /usr/local` and show the output?

Comment: It's all `uid=mark`, `gid=admin`.